# Pronunciation of ä

Tags: pronunciation

AFAIK a short "ä" is always pronounced /ɛ/ in German, but is there a consensus among native German speakers about the pronunciation of a long "ä" ? Different sources say different things about it:

- "ä" is always pronounced /ɛ:/, a longer version of the phoneme of the letter "e" in the English word "bed" (US pronunciation in IPA syntax: /bɛd/)
- "ä" is always pronounced /e:/, a longer version of the first phoneme of the letter "A" in the English word "April" (US pronunciation in IPA syntax: /ˈeɪ.pɹəl/)

However, the pronunciation I hear in different German words is not consistent with any of those two rules. Example: in http://joycep.myweb.port.ac.uk/pronounce/vowelae.html , "Mädchen" is pronounced /ˈmeːtçən/ , "kläglich" /klɛ:gliç/ , "wählen" /ˈvɛːlən/ and "Währung" /ˈveːʁʊŋ/ . Is it a regional difference?

Comment: I think it comes from laziness. Pronouncing Mädchen with /eː/ doesn't require you to open your mouth as wide as with /ɛ:/

Comment: There's surely _some_ regionality involved. In standard eastern Austrian, long "ä" is always realized as [e:] (_sehen_ == _sähen_), as far as I can tell; and I believe it tends to become an actual [ɛː] the more northern you go in Germany.  Anyway, we're talking about _phonetics_ here, so [square brackets] are appropriate. The underlying phoneme is always /ɛː/, contrasting with /eː/.

Comment: ^ that, and not to mention expression of kind of dramatic emphasis.

Comment: @phipsgabler However, the Northern German pronunciation of *Städte* sounds like 'Steete'

Comment: @phipsgabler Isn't the pronunciation the other way around in Germany? According to https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/M%C3%A4dchen , https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6782/is-there-a-practical-difference-between-e-and-%c3%a4 and https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/e-und-%C3%A4.134616/ , the long "ä" is pronounced [e:] in Northern Germany.

Comment: OK, that can totally be. I just assumed it to go in the opposite direction the further away you go from Austria. Maybe there's two poles, one in South Bavarian and one in Low German dialects? I couldn't find any references, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In standard German, a short "ä" is indeed pronounced /ɛ/.

In standard German, a long "ä" is pronounced [ɛː], but the pronunciation differs in some dialects. For instance, it is pronounced [eː] in northern Germany. As the media usually follows a northern dialect, it is common to hear a long "ä" pronounced as [e:] in German movies, TV series and news broadcasting.

Comment: The media don't follow the Berlin dialect -- which is a relatively young, eclectic metrolect -- at all! (At least not outside of Mario Barth's TV show and the regional broadcaster *RBB*.) If they did, they would, e.g., say *ick* for *ich* or *ooch* instead of *auch*. At most, the media follow an *accent*, and that would probably be the one of Hanover. NB that in regard of TV broadcasters, Cologne and Munich are *much* bigger locations than Berlin, and Hamburg arguably exceeds Berlin for print media.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus Thanks for the feedback. As the recently successful "Dark" TV series was produced in Berlin and its surroundings, I have (probably incorrectly) generalized that most movies and series were produced and filmed there. I'll fix my answer.