# Käsearten: Wie spricht man das "ä" in Käse aus?

Tags: phonetics

In dieser Wikipediaseite (Link unten) steht, dass der Laut **"ä"** in **Käse** dem Internationalen Phonetischen Alphabet zufolge als **/ɛ:/** ausgesprochen werden soll, wie im Französischen "*frÈre*" (eher /ɛ/, kurzes /ɛ:/) oder Portugiesischen "*pÉ*".

Jedoch hört es sich für meine (ausländischen) Ohren etwas komisch an, **da ich seit jeher dieses "ä" als einfaches /e:/ gehört und ausgesprochen habe**. Unterscheidet sich hier die Aussprache je nach Dialekt bzw. Region? So /kɛ:ze/ oder /ke:ze/?

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aussprache_der_deutschen_Sprache

Könntet ihr Beispiele geben, wo der /ɛ:/ auftaucht?

Comment: Damit zusammenhängende Frage auf Englisch: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6782/is-there-a-practical-difference-between-e-and-%c3%a4

Comment: Danke. Da ist schon alles erklärt.

Comment: Wenn dieselbe Frage einmal auf Englisch und ein anderes Mal auf Deutsch gestellt wird, ist das **KEIN** Grund, die Frage als Duplikat zu behandeln und zu schließen. Siehe https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/807/what-to-do-with-duplicate-questions-in-another-language

Comment: In diesem Fall wurde die Frage vom Fragesteller geschlossen, da für ihn alles geklärt war.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bei Muttersprachlern hört man sowohl /kɛ:ze/ als auch /ke:ze/, abhängig vom Akzent.

Spontan fällt mir "Cäsar" ein, was üblicherweise auch mit einem langem /ɛ:/ ausgesprochen wird.